# Add cross-browser underline to "select" in gridview - asp.net

Tags: asp.net, select, gridview, underline

What is the easiest way to add an underline to the dynamically auto added select button that is in the first column.  see the code below , this does not work.

Can I do this in the vb.net  as I want to change the color too and maybe add an image?
This works on my localhost, but not when I deploy it to a IIS6 environment.

```
  For Each row As GridViewRow In Me.gv.Rows
     gv.Rows(row.RowIndex).Cells(0).Font.Underline = True  
  Next
```